# SSIS - Using ODBC SQL execute task having parameters into a resultset to be imported

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, intersystems

First thing first.  I'm totally new to SSIS and trying to figure out its potential when it comes to ETL and eventually go to SSAS.  I have the following scenario:

1. I have an Intersystems Database which I can connect via ADO `.NET`
2. I want to take data from this db and make inserts into MS SQL through incremental loads

My proposed solution/target is:

1. Have table in the MS SQL that stores the last pointer read or date/time snapshot. (irrevevant at this stage).  Let's keep it simple and say we are going to use the record ID that exists in the Intersystems Database
2. Get the pointer from this table and use it as a parameter through ODBC to read the source database and then make inserts into the target MS SQL db
3. Update the pointer with the last record read so that next time we continue from there. (I don't want to get into the complications of updates/deletes. let's keep it simple)

Progress so far:

1. I have succeed to make a connection with MS SQL to read the pointer from there and place it in a variable
2. I have managed to use the `[Execute SQL task]` using parameters to read data from Intersystems Db and I'm placing that into a variable using `FullResultSet`
3. I have managed to use the `[ForEach Loop Container]` using the `[Foreach ADO Enumerator]` to go through each record and each field (yeeeey!)

Now. I can use a `[Script task]` that makes inserts into the MS SQL database using `VB.NET` code (theoretically) and then update the counter with the last record read from the source database. I have spent endless hours looking for solutions using ODBC parameters and the above is the only way forward I could see working.

**My question is this:**

**Is this the only way and best practise?  Isn't there some easy way that I can plug this resultset into some dataflow components which does the inserts and updates the record pointer for me??**

Please assume that I do not have rights access to write into Intersystems Db and thus I cannot make any changes there to the tables structures. But I can only read data so that I can place it into MS SQL.

Over to you guys (or gals?)

Comment: You should be using a data flow instead of execute sql into a variable and process row by row in a foreach. I'll expand below in an answer

Comment: You're looking for [Stairway to Integration Series, Level 4 Updating Rows in Incremental Loads](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/76390/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a dataflow to improve your design for both efficiency (bulk loading vs row by row in script) and ease of use (no need for scripting).

1. You should use an execute SQL to get your pointer and save it into a variable.
2. You should build a sql variable using dynamic sql and above variable.
3. Make a data connection in manager to Source
4. Add a dataflow and go into it
5. Add a source manager and select your source from popup
6. Choose sql from variable and choose your variable

At this  point you should have all the data you want and you can continue to transform or directly load to your target.

Edit: Record Pointer part

7. Add a multicast (this makes as many copies as you want)
8. Add an Aggregate Object and max(whatever your pointer is)
9. OleDBSQL Object (Allows live SQL and used mainly for updates

9a. UPDATE "YourPointerTable" SET "PointerField in DB" = ?  (? is actually what you need to enter.

9b. Map to whatever you named in step 8.

This will allow you to handle insert/updates

10. From Multicast flow a new stream to a lookup object and map your key to the key of destination table
11. Specify no matches to redirect to no match output
12. Your matches map to an UPDATE
13. Your no matches map to an Insert

Comment: KeithL - "I would suggest using a dataflow to improve your design ".  This was my first attempt. But found out that an ODBC datasource within a dataflow does not support parameters. There  is no option and if you put ? it would give an error when 'parsing' the sql query.  That is why I have opted the 'Execute SQL task' to get the data, as it was the only option to support parameters.